# How to read the attribute name (stored in variable) of JSON using node.js

Tags: json, node.js

```
for (var tablename in original.test) {
  tableName = tablename;
}
```

`tableName` contains the attribute name of the JSON. How to read the value within the attribute `tableName`? I tried the following way but not working:

```
for (var index in "original.test."+tableName+" ) {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
original.test[tableName]
```

Please try google in future.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
original.test[tableName]
```

When you try `original.test.tableName` it tries to find the property called "tableName"